# How does Firestore auto index each field entity and still work fast?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am reading [Firestore indexing](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/concepts/index-overview#query_scopes) and this statement really struck me

> By default, Firestore automatically maintains single-field indexes for
> each field in a document and each subfield in a map.

How exactly is this possible, doesn't indexes actually slow down inserting, what if I have a document with many properties say ten, and on of them has a varying list of items?

> For each array field in a document, Firestore creates and maintains a
> collection-scope array-contains index.

So if I have 100 docs with each having 10-100 items in some list, let's call it items do I have 100 X 100 indexes?

Answer (score 0):

It's all about how the data is spread out over the disks.

- If data that is being written sequentially is far from each other on the disks, it can be large written in parallel and the operations complete quickly.
- If the data contains values that are close to each other on disk, you will experience hotspots in writes in certain areas and the performance goes down.

So if your data has a pretty uniform, random distribution you can have good write performance. But when documents you are writing in sequence have the same or consistently sequential values for a certain index, write performance will be lower.

An exception to this is when you use the [BulkWriter operations](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/firestore/bulkwriter), which I always assume perform bulk updates of the documents and indexes - but I never really checked if that's the case.